# Long text display

Tags: android

I am new to Android Developments. I intend creating studying app which allows users to read long writing on their phones' screen. I want a hint on how to do it. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Joe. If you're already familiar with android try out a few things and then revert back here when you run into trouble. If you don't know android, go have a look at this link https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html

Comment: You can use `ScrollView` and add `TextView` to it. Textview's width and height must be `match_parent`

Answer (score 0):

You can make your TextView scrollable and multiline to achieve this:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/receipt"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text=""/>
</ScrollView>
```